# C# SVG rendering engine - doesn't convert PostScript font but TrueType font does convert?

Tags: c#, svg, fonts, truetype, postscript

I have problem with NuGet package SVG rendering engine for C#.

I created 2 my own fonts. First font name is PostScript (have PostScrypt lines) and font name of second is TrueType (have TrupeType lines).
[IMG Font informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsmwB.png)

I do program which convert my SVG code to bitmap image and show him.
When i convert it, then i get this: [IMG Result of conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o839X.png)

TrueType font convert successfully but PostScript font doesn't.
I dont know what i can do with this. Please help.

There is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Xml;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Test_Wpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox.SelectAll();
            string svg = richTextBox.Selection.Text;

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmldoc.LoadXml(svg);

                Svg.SvgDocument svgdoc = Svg.SvgDocument.Open(xmldoc);

                Bitmap bmp = svgdoc.Draw();

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

                BitmapImage bim = new BitmapImage();
                bim.BeginInit();
                bim.StreamSource = ms;
                bim.EndInit();
                bim.Freeze();

                image.Source = bim;

                ShowMsg("Successfully converted. No Errors.");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ShowMsg(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void ShowMsg(string msg)
        {
            label.Content = String.Format("[{0}] - {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code examples and any error messages you encounter.

Comment: Thats that problem, i dont get any error messages. It convert successfully.

Comment: I added my C# code. SVG code is in second link.

Comment: Can you also show what it is supposed to look like? (Yes, there is SVG code at the bottom of your image. I'm not going to type it in just to check. Please help us help you.)

Comment: You have not supplied either font. The most likely problem is that the PostScript font you have created does not have an Encoding suitable for use with the text encoding you are using (apparently ASCII ?). In short there is nothing wrong with your code, you have simply created the font in a way which won't work the way you expect.

Comment: Another possibility, of course, is that the viewer simply doesn't understand PostScript font formats. You say its your own code but you seem to be relying on the OS support for the actual work.